# Selected placemarkers from fusion table not showing up in google earth

Tags: google-fusion-tables, google-earth

I have a Google fusion table which defines an "icon" column which selects one of the standard placemarker names for each row, e.g. 'large_blue'. You can see that this is working on this map view:

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1JJHwwJLW1CqrG3PZv3kMBrRJio-5f_28g_rJrYU#map:id=3

But when I export that as KML, the markers are all the default yellow pushpin. Shouldn't the selected markers carry over into the KML? Is there something else I need to do to make that happen?

Comment: Not currently available. See this [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=36).

Comment: Comment 42 on that bug says this should now work. https://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=36#c42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supposed to work, but the exported KML from your map is lacking style tags entirely. This appears to be a bug. Please email googletables-feedback@google.com with a description of the problem and we'll take a look.

Comment: The bug is now fixed, and my KML download includes proper style information, resulting in the markers I expect to see in Earth. Thanks!